# How can I retrieve previous sent email from outlook exchange 2007 to evolution

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-gnome, evolution, ms-exchange, davmail

I have evolution 3.36.4-0ubuntu1, in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
I use it to connect to MS Exchange 2007 configured with Davmail.
It works very well, the only detail is that it can't retrieve previous sent mail from exchange, new sent mail appears in the sent folder as it should.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: that's an Exchange problem - unless you have other Sent folders you aren't subscribed to (I see several when I try and use excahnge, different clients use different folders), you are only seeing the default sent folder that Evolution is trying to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help. 
Everything in exchange is as default and I did not find any other folder that could be causing conflict.